# calculate double integral on quadrangle domain by changing of variables

Tags: integration

Problem: calculate double integral $\iint_D dA$ on quadrangle domain $D$ give by vertices $(1,1),(4,2),(2,4),(3,5)$.

How can I change variables to get double integral on form $\int_a^b \int_{c(x)}^{d(x)} |J(x,y)|dA$ ?

Answer (score 1):

let the straight lines made by the points $(1,1)(4,2)\to I$ ,$(1,1)(2,4)\to II$ ,$(2,4)(3,5)\to III$ and $(3,5)(4,2)\to IV$

the equations of the lines are 
$$I \to y=\frac{1}{3}x+\frac{2}{3}$$
$$II \to y=3x-2$$
$$III \to y=x+2$$
$$IV \to y=-3x+14$$
if you graph the quadrangular domain . you see
$$A=\int_{1}^{2}\int_{I}^{II}dydx+ \int_{2}^{3}\int_{I}^{III}dydx+ \int_{3}^{4}\int_{I}^{IV}dydx$$

Comment: I know you divide domain to small domains. But I want to calculate double integral which not need to divide. How can you do it?, or we have no any way to do it.

Comment: a general function for the quadrangular domain will not be possible as it is not continuous.